# invariance of defining sets for abelian codes by isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-rings

An abelian code is an ideal of the $\mathbb{F}$ algebra:
$$
A(n_1,\ldots,n_l):= \dfrac{\mathbb{F}[X_1,\ldots,X_l]}{[X_{1}^{n_1}-1,
\ldots,X_{l}^{n_l}-1]}
$$
Given an ideal $C$ in this algebra, there exists a defining set $D(C)$ that characterizes it entirely.
See: https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1803
for more details.
In the article "Information Sets From Defining Sets in Abelian Codes" by Jacobo and Bernal,
available at https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1803 page 7993,
there is a statement that says the following:
If $\varphi$ is an isomorphism:
$$
\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}
$$
and $C$ is a cyclic code over $\mathbb{F}[X_1]/[X^{n}-1]$
with defining set $\mathcal{D}(C)$,
then $\varphi(C)$ is an abelian code over
$\mathbb{F}[X_1,X_2]/[X^{n_1}_{1}-1,X^{n_2}_{2}-1]$,
and it holds that,
$\mathcal{D}(\varphi(C))=\varphi(\mathcal{D}(C))$.
I managed to prove this result when $\varphi$ is the isomorphism obtained by the
Chinese Remainder Theorem, but not in the general case.
I am grateful for any help.